# Unable to locate/click pop-up button with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, popup

I'm using Selenium in Python 3 to access webpages, and I want to click on a pop-up button, but I am unable to locate it with Selenium.

What I'm describing below applies to a number of sites with a pop-up, so I'll use a simple example.

```
url = "https://www.google.co.uk"

from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get(url)
```

The page has a pop-up for agreeing to cookies.

[image: page with pop-up]

**I want the script to click on the "I agree" button, but I'm unable to locate it.**

I've found a few questions and posts about this online (including on Stackoverflow), but all the suggestions I found seem to fall in one of the following categories and don't seem to work for me.

1. Wait longer for the pop-up to actually load.

I've tried adding delays, and in fact, I'm testing this interactively, so I can wait all I want for the page to load before I try to locate the button, but it doesn't make any difference.

2. Use something like `driver.switch_to.alert`

I get a `NoAlertPresentException`. The pop-up doesn't seem to be an *alert*.

3. Locate the element using `driver.find_element`.

This doesn't work either, regardless of which approach I use (xpath, class name, text etc.). I can find elements from the page under the pop-up, but nothing from the pop-up itself. For example,

```
# Elements in main page (under pop-up)
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Sign in") # returns FirefoxWebElement
driver.find_element_by_class_name("gb_g") # returns FirefoxWebElement

# Elements on the pop-up
driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("I agree") # NoSuchElementException
driver.find_element_by_class_name("RveJvd snByac") # NoSuchElementException
```

**The popup just doesn't seem to be there in the page source**. In fact, if I try looking at the loaded page source from the browser, I can't find anything related to the pop-up. I understand that many sites use client-side scripts to load elements dynamically, so many elements wouldn't show up in the raw source, but that was the point of using Selenium: to load the page, interpret the scripts and access the end result.

So, what am I doing wrong? Where is the pop-up coming from, and how can I access it?

Comment: is using `--headless` an option or do you need the window?

Comment: give an example link in the code..I see no pop-up.

Comment: @AbrarAhmed, I don't need to see the window, but I need a browser that can interpret JS etc. to load the content I want to access with the script. I believe I can't use `--headless` for that.

Comment: @AbrarAhmed, I've included both the URL of the page and a screenshot with the pop-up in the question. To get the pop-up, you might need to log out of any Google accounts and clear your cookies.

Comment: Have you tried with browser debugging tools? I could see (on Firefox) the following line when I used the inspector on "I agree" button: `<span class="RveJvd snByac">I agree</span>`.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @Callum: nope, it's still open.

Comment: @Ratler, did you finally manage to overcome this? I am facing exactly same issue. I even tried to get hold of the 2nd window using "handle.window_handles" and then switch. But, no luck. Pls share the details if you were able to get pass through this one.

Comment: @Patz, I haven't solved this, and I stopped trying some time ago, but if you manage to figure it out, please let us know here since it looks like it's troubling quite a few people.